# Trying to get a "button" from a child window

Tags: c#, pinvoke

I will start by saying that my experience with pinvoke is extremely limited. I know very little of C++, too. But here is my situation...

I have a program in C# that uses pinvoke to get functions like `SendMessage` and `FindWindow` and the like from C++. It looks for the name of the window, gets the handles, etc. This works fine right now. I will put the code down a bit lower.

Now I have a situation where I want to find a "button" on one of the child windows. I have the `IntPtr` of the **Actual Child Window**, at least I think it is. I am very confused about what is a window and what isn't.

I am trying to use `EnumChildWindows` and `FindWindowByCaption` and `FindWindowEx` etc to go through all of the children and find this button. I can get its "caption" with Spy++, but giving that to the `FindWindowByCaption` does not yield anything.

This is the code that actually finds the parent window. I am sorry if it is confusing, it is being run against very old software.

This is all in C#, using pInvoke. I try to first get the button I want with this method..

`FindWindowByCaption(IntPtr.Zero, "{{Caption as shown by Spy++}}");`

This doesn't work, even though I give it the right caption. So I try this... In this example, `Handle` is the `IntPtr` of the parent window that contains the button I want to find.

```
// create a small counter so that we do not try to check
// too many windows and crash the program.
int i = 0;
var previous = new Window();
var current = new Window();

do {

    current = 
        new Window(
            InteropServices.FindWindowEx(
            Handle,
            previous.Handle,
            null, null
        )
    );
    if (current == IntPtr.Zero)
        break;

    // add current to list

    // continue
    previous = current; // never finds the right button, either.
    ++i;
} while (i < 500);
```

But even at this, the control I want is never found. Can anyone help me with this? It is getting very frustrating. I can see the `Caption` in Spy++, I can see that it has a handle. It does not appear to be anything special.

Comment: FindWindowEx() can find a window by its class name or its caption.  You give it no chance by passing *null* for both.

Comment: "I am very confused about what is a window and what isn't." - That's not surprising, given that a lot of things that are windows in one program are not windows in another program. You're checking with Spy++, which is one good way of determining. If you can see it in there, it's a window.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do the following:

1. Call `FindWindow` to find the top-level window. Use either class name, or window title, or both, to identify it.
2. Call `FindWindowEx` repeatedly to find child windows. Pass the parent window as `hwndParent` and `NULL` as `hwndChildAfter`. Again use either class name, or window title, or both, to identify the child window.
3. Eventually you will descend the parent/child window hierarchy until you reach your target window.

So, for an example, consider the following hierarchy, using Spy++ notation:

```
Window 00001000 "My MainForm window title" "MainFormWindowClass"
|
-- Window 00002000 "Panel container" "PanelWindowClass"
   |
   -- Window 00003000 "Click me!" "ButtonWindowClass"
```

You would find this with the following sequence of calls:

```
HWND main = FindWindow("MainFormWindowClass", NULL); // just use class name
HWND panel = FindWindowEx(main, NULL, "PanelWindowClass", "Panel container");
HWND button = FindWindowEx(panel, NULL, "ButtonWindowClass", "Click me!");
```

Note that I've written this in C++ to avoid confounding things with p/invoke. And I've also omitted all error checking for the sake of a clean example. You obviously would check for errors.

I suggest that you keep Spy++ at hand and try to write a simple C++ console application that locates your window. Once you know the sequence of calls to `FindWindow` and `FindWindowEx` that do the job, translate them to C#.

Comment: Yeah... this is exactly what I have, and it is still returning `0`. I look at the button through `Spy++`, and then I give it the handle of the parent it is on. This also matches in Spy++ (except it is in Hex in Spy, and it is an IntPtr in my code). But when I try to get the handle of the button, it comes back as 0.

Comment: But I can get other controls on that window just fine.

Comment: Is there a difference in the Window Title and the Window Caption? It tells me a Caption in Spy++, but if I simply list ALL child windows and have it print their Title/Caption, the one with the correct Handle has a blank caption

Comment: Alright, I have discovered what I think is the problem. The problem is that the `Caption` is not the same thing apparently. When getting the Caption using `GetWindowText`, it fails. But when I get it using `SendMessage` and passing in `WM_GETTEXT`, it succeeds. I still cannot use `FindWindow`, but I can get ALL child windows, and then enumerate them to find the matching one.